# Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-powerpc/Packages'

Tags: lubuntu, 32-bit, powerpc, cgminer

I have installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my old 15" PowerBook G4, 32-bit laptop, and am now trying to install Wine HQ software so that I can use windows 32-bit programs. I keep getting the following error:

```
Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-powerpc/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am not a developer and this is my first time trying Ubuntu, so it would be great to get clear step-by-step instructions on what I need to do... if a solution is possible? I have managed to install WiFi drivers and resolve a few other errors by reading the Q&As on this site, but have not found a solution to the above error. If the problem could be solved by changing to another version of Lubuntu or another distro, I could also try that. Please give me your recommendations :-)

Comment: wine only has amd64 and i386 versions.

Comment: “now trying to install Wine HQ software so that I can use windows 32-bit programs” Wine can't magically convert instructions across totally different architectures (PPC and x86). See also: https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS_FAQ#Will_there_be_a_PowerPC_version_.28or_will_there_be_a_way_to_run_Wine_on_a_PowerPC_processor.29.3F

Answer (score 3):

The repository you're using does not include package for the PowerPC platform your Powerbook uses. It only supports `i386` (for 32bit pcs) and `amd64` (for 64bit pcs).

The reason is likely that the original wine does not really support running on PowerPC platforms.

Comment: Thanks Florian. But my PowerBook G4 is a 32 bit computer? Also the same error appears when I try to download other programs so it’s not specific to Wine. Can you advise how to fix the error? Or is there another program like Wine that I can run on my PowerBook?  My objective is to run some crypto mining software on the PowerBook so if you (or anyone else) can recommend a miner that works then that would be a big help. Currently I’m stuck with this :-(

Comment: @roaster the fact that your laptop uses 32bit data types does not matter. It has a PowerPC architecture and the software you are trying to run (Wine) is made for a x86 (Intel-compatible) architecture.